# Why does the non-breaking space produce a double space with babel and \og and how to use both \og and non-breaking space?

Tags: spacing, typography, babel, frenchspacing

I am wondering if this is a normal situation or a bug!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}

Ceci est \og entre guillemets \fg.

Ceci est aussi \og~entre guillemets~\fg, mais avec des espaces insécables.

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

**Is there a way to use both a non-breaking space and the symbol \og?**

---

PS :

```
Ceci est aussi \og{}~entre guillemets~\fg{}, mais avec des espaces insécables.
```

gives the same.

Comment: `\og` already contains some spacing commands: `\penalty \@M \hskip .8\fontdimen 2\font plus.3\fontdimen
3\font minus.8\fontdimen 4\font`

Comment: You can also use [csquotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes), a package for intelligent quoting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to be very logical: `\og` and `\fg` do add unbreakable spaces. So if you specify them explicitly, it considers you want to have two of them on each side. I think you also can use directly « and » in your code, provided you don't forget to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` (and an 8-bit font, not cm fonts). See §9 of the doc for `frenchb`.

Answer (score 7):

This is a question of how tex interprets its input.  In `\og` , `\og` followed by space, the final space is swallowed as a terminator for the command and no space is printed.  In `\og~` the `~` inserts a space into the output.  This is similar to `\og{}` , `\og{}` followed by space, which also inserts a space:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}

Ceci est \og{} entre guillemets\fg.

\end{document}
```

Now do you need to instert a non-breakable space after `\og`?  No.  `\og` inserts penalties disallowing a line break immediately after.