# Missing space after "guillemets"

Tags: spacing, babel, french

I have a problem with the `\og` and `\fg` characters for opening and closing "guillemet". The closing guillemet is always too close to whatever follows, in other words, there is missing space between `\fg` and the next word that follows. I'm using TeXmaker, and a typical piece of code where the problem occurs is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
Lalala \og blabla \fg lalala.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71035/wrong-spacing-around-guillemets and Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149330/why-does-the-non-breaking-space-produce-a-double-space-with-babel-and-og-and-ho

Comment: You have to add `{}` after `\fg`

Comment: @karlkoeller that does it! Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to get the correct spacing between `\fg` and a word following it, you have to add an empty statement `{}` after it.

This because the definition of `\fg` in `frenchb.ldf` resorts to the definition of `\FB@fg` which is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\FB@fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi
                           \FBguill@spacing\guillemotright\xspace}
```

As you can see, this command takes no arguments, so it inserts no space after it, if you don't break the command explicitly with `{}` (or `\` which is not advisable).

The behavior is the same as if you define a new command with no arguments

```
\newcommand{\qqq}{qqq}
```

and use it as

```
\qqq word
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
Lalala \og blabla \fg{} lalala.
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also notice that the definition of `\FB@fg` contains an `\xspace` at its end. This means that, if you don't want to insert `{}` each time you use `\fg`, you can simply load the package `xspace`.

The following MWE gives the same result as in the above picture:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{xspace}
\begin{document}
Lalala \og blabla \fg lalala.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

For some reason beyond my understanding, using the keyboard guillemets `«` and `»` together with the following option in the `babel` package

```
\frenchbsetup{og=«,fg=»}
```

solves the problem (and elegantly too). Of course, one needs access to utf8 characters. Here is a full example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{og=«,fg=»}

\begin{document}

Ceci est du «texte» entre guillemets.

\end{document}
```

[image: typeset text with guillemets]
<sub>(source: [univ-mlv.fr](http://perso-math.univ-mlv.fr/users/romon.pascal/dl/guillemets.png))</sub>

Comment: Does this not also require some input encoding to be specified? Could you post a full example please and elaborate on your post?

Comment: Good point. I edited the post and added a full example. Thanks.